Anki installation issue on Arch Linux
I am trying to install Anki from the AUR. However when I try to build the package, I am told the package failed to build. I have tried installing the package manually, and I have tried using Yay and Paru. On Paru I have tried all 4 versions (anki, anki-bin, anki-git, and anki-Qt5). One of the warnings is that 'Resolution field "cookie@0.7.0" is incomaptible with the required version cookie@0.6.0". I am given a number of Python errors such as "can't import _build_backend" and "iife" output formatting is not possible from "meta.en". I am told that "force_qt5.patch" failed to pass the validity test. Has anyone else has similar issues with installing Anki on Arch Linux and does anyone have a solution? I am using an older computer (circa 2006) with Radeon graphics. If the issue cannot be resolved, does anyone know of good third-party alternative clients for Anki? Many thanks
